# How do I create an if statement inside another if statement with javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am making a poker game with HTML CSS and Javascript.  Right now, I am making the part of the program that actually deals the cards.   I need to have an if statement inside another if statement.  When it runs through, it generates a random number, then I have a list of if statements that see first if the card has been chosen, then I have another if statement inside of the first if statement to see if the card has been dealt.  I don't know why it won't work.  Can anyone help?  Here is the code:

```
var yourchipsvar = 500;
var alchipsvar = 500;
var potvar = 0;
var whotodealto = 0;

yourchipsvar = Number(yourchipsvar);
alchips = Number(alchipsvar);
potvar = Number(potvar);

document.getElementById("yourchips").innerHTML = Number(yourchipsvar);
document.getElementById("alchips").innerHTML = Number(alchipsvar);
document.getElementById("pot").innerHTML = Number(potvar);


function bet() {

  yourchipsvar = yourchipsvar - 5;
  potvar = potvar + 5;
  yourchipsvar = Number(yourchipsvar);
  potvar = Number(potvar);
  document.getElementById("pot").innerHTML = potvar;
  document.getElementById("yourchips").innerHTML = yourchipsvar;
}

function bet15() {

  yourchipsvar = yourchipsvar - 15;
  potvar = potvar + 15;
  yourchipsvar = Number(yourchipsvar);
  potvar = Number(potvar);
  document.getElementById("pot").innerHTML = potvar;
  document.getElementById("yourchips").innerHTML = yourchipsvar;
}

function bet25() {

  yourchipsvar = yourchipsvar - 25;
  potvar = potvar + 25;
  yourchipsvar = Number(yourchipsvar);
  potvar = Number(potvar);
  document.getElementById("pot").innerHTML = potvar;
  document.getElementById("yourchips").innerHTML = yourchipsvar;
}

function bet50() {

  yourchipsvar = yourchipsvar - 50;
  potvar = potvar + 50;
  yourchipsvar = Number(yourchipsvar);
  potvar = Number(potvar);
  document.getElementById("pot").innerHTML = potvar;
  document.getElementById("yourchips").innerHTML = yourchipsvar;
}
var aceofspades = 0;
var twoofspades = 0;
var threeofspades = 0;
var fourofspades = 0;
var fiveofspades = 0;
var cardinhand = 0;

function deal() {
  if (whotodealto == 0) {
    dealuser();
  } else {
    alert("dealtotheAI");
  }
}

function dealuser() {
  var cardinhand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);

  if (cardinhand == 0) {
    if (aceofspades == 0) {
      alert("You got an ace of spades");
      var aceofspades = 1;
    }
  }

  if (cardinhand == 1) {
    if (twoofspades == 0) {
      alert("You got a two of spades");
      var twoofspades = 1;
    }
  }

  if (cardinhand == 2) {
    if (threeofspades == 0) {
      alert("You got a three of spades");
      var threeofspades = 1;
    }
  }

  if (cardinhand == 3) {
    if (fourofspades == 0) {
      alert("You got a four of spades");
      var fourofspades = 1;
    }
  }

  if (cardinhand == 4) {
    if (fiveofspades == 0) {
      alert("You got a five of spades");
      var fiveofspades = 1;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Try removing the "var" in these lines: if(aceofspades==0){alert("You got an ace of spades"); var aceofspades = 1;}...

Comment: why do you need two if statement in `dealuser()`. Your two if's can be bundled together and the logic would still be same - `if(cardinhand==1 && aceofspades==0) {//do something}`

Comment: Looks like you can use loops in some places and simply have a single `bet()` function with an argument `bet(value)` and use `value` other than your magic numbers.

Comment: Learn the lost art of desk-checking and debugging. It solves most problems and makes you a better coder in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating two different local variables for each `aceofspades`, `twoofspades`, etc. This is because `var` means to create a local variable in the scope you are in. So the variables defined here:

```
var aceofspades = 0;
var twoofspades = 0;
var threeofspades = 0;
var fourofspades = 0;
var fiveofspades = 0;
var cardinhand = 0;

function deal() {
    if(whotodealto==0){dealuser();}  else{alert("dealtotheAI");}}

function dealuser() {
    var cardinhand = Math.floor(Math.random()*6);

    ...
}
```

Are different from the ones you create here:

```
 function dealuser() {
    ...
    if(aceofspades==0){
        alert("You got an ace of spades"); 
        var aceofspades = 1;
    }
```

In that case `var aceofspades` means you are creating a local variable in the `dealuser()` function. Simply set the value of your already created variable, this way you are not making a new one:

```
if(aceofspades==0) {
    alert("You got an ace of spades"); 
    aceofspades = 1;
}
```